# How to move the last txt file from 1 folder to another

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on a script that copys, moves, or renames the last file found in a folder

I'm not looking at last created, last modified, or newer, just looking to grab the last file found in a folder based on A-Z filename

Now I did search your site and found How to move the last modified file, or created file, but in my case it needs to be the last file

Here is the script

```
pushd Folder1
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b ') do set newest=%%a
copy "%newest%" Folder2
popd
```

The results I get is a no ext file named Folder2

I also tried

```
for /f in ("Folder1") do (
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b ') do set lastfile=%%a
move "%lastfile%" Folder2
)
```

and I tried a renaming

```
pushd Folder1
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b ') do set lastfile=%%a
ren "%lastfile%" "Folder2\NewFile.txt"
popd
```

This is what I'm aiming to get as results

```
Before
Folder1
...filename1.txt
...filename2.txt

Results
Folder1
...filename1.txt

Folder2
...NewFilename.txt
```

Comment: 1. Your `dir` is incorrect. You also need `/a-d` to eliminate directory names and `/od` for order by date not name. 2. "folder2" is a legitimate filename provided there is no **subdirectory** `folder2` in the current directory. Therefore for your first two batches, you need `completepathtoFolder2`. `Ren` can only be used to change the name a file/directory in the specified directory, so the "newname" may not contain a path.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found another way around

Here is how to find your last file, I based it on a Rename, So this will track your last txt file in your folder and it will rename it to what ever you want it to be
and then I made a move script to move the new filename.txt to the required folder

```
pushd Folder1
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b ') do set LastFile=%%a
ren "%LastFile%" NewFileName.txt
popd

move "Folder1\NewFileName.txt" "Folder2"
```

This works for me

Hopefully it helps others

Comment: This completely ignores the advice you've been given in the comments. There is nothing to define the last file, as you've not mentioned what determines it. So whilst it may have worked for you, there is currently little in the above, which offers usefulness to future readers.

Comment: That code renames and moves the last file __or__ folder __or__ reparse point (link) output by the file system (local alphabetic sorted on NTFS, unpredictable sort order on FAT32, exFAT). It might __by chance__ work for you due to content of `Folder1` and names of the files in this folder, but it is definitely not the solution to move the __file__ with newest last modification date to a different folder. That would require the usage of `pushd "Folder1" && (for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D-L /B /O-D /TW 2^>nul') do move /Y "%%I" "Folder2\NewFileName.txt" & popd & exit /B)`

Comment: @mofi my goal is to move the last file, not by date,  or newest, or last modified, the files are generated in order, but the file name and names them a-z so the last file could have been the first file created but then it was given a name for example Zorrow, which it will place it at the end of the list and not the first, so I would need to grab the last file in the folder, based on A-Z